# PHP Dropdown list maintain on reload

Tags: php, mysql

I am new to PHP and have just started the professional development in this language. I have created a dynamic dropdown list in php as under:

```
$sql="select DISTINCT State from branchinfo";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    if($result->num_rows > 0)
    {
        echo "< SELECT NAME='states'>";
        while($row=$result->fetch_assoc())
        {
            echo "< OPTION NAME = '" . $row['State'] . "'" . " VALUE = '" . $row['State'] . "'>" . $row["State"]; 
        }<br>
        echo "< /SELECT>";
    }
    echo "< INPUT TYPE='submit' name='submit' value='submit'>";
```

Problem is when I select a state and click on submit, the list reloads and my selection is lost, the first option gets selected by default. I have tried to embed the script within OPTION but it didn't worked,  I tried it as under:

```
    echo "< OPTION NAME='" . $row['State'] . "'" . " VALUE='" . $row['State'] . "'" . if(isset($_POST["submit"])){ if($_POST["states"] == $row['State']) echo "selected";} . " >" . $row["State"];<br>
```

I am not using any javasrcipt / jquery till now on this page and not planning to use it either. plz provide a solution within this code. Please help.

### Some additional information

The mthod i tried as mentioned above, works fine on hardcoded static drop downlist items written in html form. It stops working for dynamically generated list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add dropdown inside form tag, then it will work.

```
$sql = "select DISTINCT State from branchinfo";

$result = $conn->query($sql);

echo "<form method='POST'>";

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

    echo "<SELECT NAME='states'>";

    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

        $sel = ( $_POST['states'] == $row['State'] ) ? "selected" : "";

        echo "< OPTION NAME = '" . $row['State'] . "'" . " VALUE = '" . $row['State'] . "' " . $sel . ">" . $row["State"] . "</OPTION>";
    }
    echo "</SELECT>";
}
echo "<INPUT TYPE='submit' name='submit' value='submit'>";
echo "</form>";
```

Comment: HiI updated my code as under:    while($row=$result->fetch_assoc())<br>
          {
           $sel = ($_POST['states'] == $row['State']) ? " selected " : "";    echo "<OPTION NAME='" . $row['State'] . "'" . " VALUE='" . $row['State'] . "' " . $sel . " >" . $row["State"]; 
          } but it didnot work

Comment: this time, i copy pasted your code but sorry, its still not working... bye the way let me share some more info: The code that i have shared in the main post is written directly in the <?php which is inside the form tag, which is inside the body tag. This may help youe understand the situation.

Comment: Sorry!! Missed the option closing tag, it will work now. Please check now.

Comment: Hi. I am still sorry to say, it didn't work for me. I am using google chrome on Ubuntu 15.04 LTS. I think this should not affect the results, but just shared it for additional info. What can be the possible reason for this problem sir?

Comment: One more thing, i tried this before and the same thing was working on static items. i mean, if i create the list using static html tags and implement selected php code even inline, it worked fine, but it is not working on dynamic list only.

Comment: Ok please do this .

1. Open the page 
2. Goto inspect element 
3. Paste the html content of that page

So i can know what is being rendered in your browser.

Comment: No sir. It just refreshes the page and shows the first item as selected.

Comment: Try this - 
$sel = ( isset($_POST['states']) && $_POST['states'] == $row['State'] ) ? "selected" : "";

echo '<OPTION NAME = "' . $row['bank'] . '"' . ' VALUE = "' . $row['State'] . '" ' . $sel . '>' . $row["State"] . '</OPTION>';

Comment: I tried above code at my end, it's working perfectly. Can you please update your question and add entire code from your file?

Comment: Hi. I broke the code that i shared in to multiple lines and finally got it to work. However the logic is still same as i was using earlier but still you helped too. So I take your answer as accepted. Thanks a lot. :)

Answer (score 0):

Use session to remember your choice. And when the page is reloaded just retrieve your previous selected value.

like

```
    while($row=$result->fetch_assoc())
        {
if($sessionvalue==$row['State']){
echo "< OPTION SELECTED NAME = '" . $row['State'] . "'" . " VALUE = '" . $row['State'] . "'>" . $row["State"]; 
}else{
echo "< OPTION NAME = '" . $row['State'] . "'" . " VALUE = '" . $row['State'] . "'>" . $row["State"]; 
}

        }
```

Comment: Hi, isn't there any direct way instead of managing another session for this work? can't we somehow use &_POST superglobal array directly somehow?

Comment: Yes you can use $_POST but remember if any one just reload the page once again [F5] the your post variable will be empty.

Comment: but when we press F5, it asks us to maintain form re-submission, isn't it?

Comment: Yes. Sorry i meant hard refresh. Yes you can use $_POST for that.

Comment: yeah thats fine with me but still the things are not working. As I replied to the post of Mr. Shrikant. plz have a look and suggest alternate solution.